# Convert an array of strings into a array of arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, perl

My goal is to convert this

```
my @array=("red", "blue", "green", ["purple", "orange"]);
```

into this

```
my @array = ( ["red"], ["blue"], ["green"], ["purple", "orange"]);
```

Current test code:

```
my @array = ("red", "blue", "green", ["purple", "orange"] );

foreach $item ( @array ) {
   #if this was Python, it would be as simple as:
   #  if is not instance(item, array):
   #     # item wasn't a list
   #     item = [item]

   if(ref($item) ne 'ARRAY'){
      #It's an array reference...
      #you can read it with $item->[1]
      #or dereference it uisng @newarray = @{$item}
      #print "We've got an array!!\n";
      print $item, "\n";
      # keep a copy of our string
      $temp = $item;
      # re-use the variable but convert to an empty list
      @item = ();
      # add the temp-copy as first list item
      @item[0] = $temp;
      # print each list item (should be just one item)
      print "$_\n" for $item;
   }else{
      #not an array in any way...
       print "ALREADY an array!!\n";

   }
}

#  EXPECTED my @array=(["red"], ["blue"], ["green"], ["purple", "orange"]);
print @array , "\n";

foreach $item (@array){
    if(ref($item) ne 'ARRAY'){
    #
    #say for $item;
    print "didn't convert properly to array\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The comment about python maps pretty directly to perl.

```
my @array = ("red", "blue", "green", ["purple", "orange"] );

foreach $item ( @array ) {
   #if this was Python, it would be as simple as:
   #  if is not instance(item, array):
   #     # item wasn't a list
   #     item = [item]
   if (ref $item ne 'ARRAY') {
       $item = [ $item ];
   }
}
```

though using map as in Borodin's answer would be more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why you want to do this, but it's

```
@array = map { ref ? $_ : [ $_ ] } @array
```

And please don't call arrays `@array`; that's what the `@` is for.

Your comment is ridiculous

```
#if this was Python, it would be as simple as:
#  if is not instance(item, array):
#     # item wasn't a list
#     item = [item]
```

If you were familiar with Perl then you wouldn't need to ask the question. You must be aware that there is no one-to-one translation from Python to Perl. Python is much less expressive than either Perl or C, but I can't imagine you demanding a simple conversion to C.

Please get over your bigotry.

Comment: It's troubling that someone's tribalism was so intense.

Comment: obviously the poster is unfamiliar with Perl, otherwise such a simple question wouldn't have been asked. The mention of Python was obviously to establish some credibility and parity between a language in which they know how to get their stuff done.

Comment: @ borodin so you're commenting on your own tribalism?

Comment: @nmz787: The OP is sufficiently familiar with Perl to write a few dozen lines of code. I don't think it's a simple question at all; what would your solution be? I don't understand your point about mentioning Python; are you saying that they were trying to prove that they aren't clueless? That seems an odd take on things, and *"if this [were] Python, it would be as simple as..."* is provocative from all but the most naive points of view. I think it is for the OP to explain their intent, and battling me over my interpretation of their words is fruitless.

Comment: I was helping OP earlier on chat elsewhere... we pieced this example together from Google snippets... based on the actual similar-enough piece of code that is failing. Yes, I was attempting to prove we are not completely clueless. Yes I am naive, like a simple compiler.

Comment: @nmz787: I like to think that I have little bias when it comes to programming languages. I have a hatred of the likes of Java and C#, but that is along the lines of preferring brown sugar in my coffee and I would never think that my preference was "right". I wonder much more about why you are attacking me, and why I have been downvoted. That is where the real tribalism lies.

Comment: @nmz787: *"I was helping OP earlier on chat elsewhere"* Then it is unreasonable of you to expect others to take a question on face value when you know that there is a lot more behind it. It is also unreasonable to take it personally when your advice results in a poorly-presented question.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it didn't fit into the test-code as it was posted. There is a for loop, can't get around it at this point. I'm not taking it personally, I just want to get the issue solved.

Comment: @nmz787: I don't understand. It is your solution that doesn't behave in the same way as the OP's code. I wouldn't normally overwrite the original data, but I wrote it that way as that is what the OP asked for. You had to write a comment to explain how to change your solution so that the original array was modified. Either way I don't see that either your answer or mine deserves a negative vote. This whole exchange is about anger and hurt feelings rather than good programming.

Comment: I don't see any language bigotry or ridiculousness in "If this were Python"; that says there is a trivlal way to do what they want in Python, but doesn't say there isn't also such a way in Perl, just that they don't know it.  You are reading into it commentary on Perl that isn't actually there.

Answer (score 0):

If you push the values to a new array, you don't need to do more than evaluate whether or not `$item` is an arrayref:

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @array=("red", "blue", "green", ["purple", "orange"]);

my @new_array;
foreach my $item (@array) {

    if ( ref($item) eq  'ARRAY' ) {
        push @new_array, $item;
    }
    else {
        push @new_array, [$item];
    }
}

print Dumper \@new_array;
```

Output from Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'red'
          ],
          [
            'blue'
          ],
          [
            'green'
          ],
          [
            'purple',
            'orange'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Why use `for` when you want `map`?

Comment: Because I matched my answer to his example. He's clearly coming from python and is new to perl. I've found it's much easier for people to adapt to a new language if you use code structures they're already familiar with.

Comment: can you answer with the in-line modification, rather than creating a new array?

Comment: That's fair, but the OP seemed to have written a solution using Perl and `for`. Doesn't it work? They didn't say either way, but I assumed it was working code that should have been as brief as their Python original. I can't run any code at present as I'm on my commute. Hopefully this will stop soon.

Comment: @Borodin: no, the example code doesn't work they way he's wanting it to. The original array remains unchanged and the item array is being overwritten in the for loop.

Comment: @nmz787: If you want to update the original array in the fewest lines possible or without explicitly copying the array to a new one, then Borodin's answer to use a map is the way to go.

Comment: @nmz787: If you just want to keep using using the original array variable after doing the modifications in my example, then you can just reassign the new array back to the old one after the loop. ( eg. `@array = @new_array;` )

Comment: @interduo: Okay. Then the OP is very badly phrased. It contains no question, and says nothing about whether the *"current test code"* is functional. The impression I got was that the question was about why Perl couldn't be as concise as Python. Your answer is a good one, and pretty much what I would write if I were asked to use loops. I don't think either your answer or mine deserve the down votes that they have, but hey, people don't like being wrong.

Comment: @Borodin: I can see how you could get that impression from the way the question is worded. I think my years doing customer support and access to an editor gave me an edge there. :) Your answer is definitely the one I would go with when writing production code.

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of learning more Perl than I ever thought/wanted to learn... here's what I think is a workable solution:

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


my %the_dict = (duts => 
                    {dut_a => {UDF => 'hamnet'},
                     dut_b => {UDF => [ '1', '2', '3', ]},
                     dut_c => {UDF => [ 'Z' ], }});

print Dumper \%the_dict;

foreach my $dut (keys %{$the_dict{duts}}) {
    # convert the dut's UDF value to an array if it wasn't already
    if ( 'ARRAY' ne ref $the_dict{duts}->{$dut}{UDF} ) { 
        $the_dict{duts}->{$dut}{UDF} = [ $the_dict{duts}->{$dut}{UDF} ]; 
    }
    # now append a new value to the array
    push(@{$the_dict{duts}{$dut}{UDF}}, 'works');
}

print Dumper \%the_dict;
```

when run we see these print-outs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'duts' => {
                      'dut_a' => {
                                   'UDF' => 'hamnet'
                                 },
                      'dut_c' => {
                                   'UDF' => [
                                              'Z'
                                            ]
                                 },
                      'dut_b' => {
                                   'UDF' => [
                                              '1',
                                              '2',
                                              '3'
                                            ]
                                 }
                    }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'duts' => {
                      'dut_a' => {
                                   'UDF' => [
                                              'hamnet',
                                              'works'
                                            ]
                                 },
                      'dut_c' => {
                                   'UDF' => [
                                              'Z',
                                              'works'
                                            ]
                                 },
                      'dut_b' => {
                                   'UDF' => [
                                              '1',
                                              '2',
                                              '3',
                                              'works'
                                            ]
                                 }
                    }
        };
```